# Extracting words from strings when string format differs (Google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, trim, texttrimming

I am trying to extract campaign names from lines of strings. The problem is that campaign name formats are different.

- What would be the best way to extract campaign names in bold in this case?
- Is it possible to do this combining IF and TRIM functions?

[image: Campaign list]

Beginnings repeat in multiple campaigns:

- AO:11112_LTV_EDP_
- AO:12311_
- RTU_EDP_CHIKITA_
- AO:15616_FI_

Campaign list:

- AO:11112_LTV_EDP_BAMBINO_All_Q1BeesAreGettingThem_mumba_jumba_v23
- AO:12311_slimyinfluencer_v24_photoad
- RTU_EDP_CHIKITA_PlainSnail_ai_karamba_v2
- AO:15616_FI_potatogoestohollywood_hail_the_snail_0

In case of single format, I was using formula:

```
=TRIM(SPLIT((MID(A2,(SEARCH("EDP",A2)),LEN(A2))),"_"))
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: unless we find a pattern, it is kind of hard to do a single formula for all.

all of them except "Snail" are pretty similar though.

Comment: Yes, if you can't express the "rules" that identify a campaign name, then there is no way to have a formula, or code, extract them.. They aren't the first word after the third underscore, or any logic that I can discern.  Can you describe in words how the campaign names were found in your examples?  Is it something like: the text before the second last underscore?

Comment: According to best practices, campaign naming should have followed:
 Country - Department - Brand - Campaign name  - campaign objective - buying method - goal
structure and look like
RTU_EDP_CHIKITA_PlainSnail_ai_karamba_v2
But it seems that it was not done so in most instances. Is there a way to write a formula if other 3 types of deviations repeat?

Comment: Only if there is some logic or consistency to the deviations.  For example, if they all left out the Brand.  Then we could search each string, and there is one missing term, we know to use the third term for Campaign, instead of the fourth.  Or if, in all cases, they always included the Campaign Name, Campaign Objective, and Buying Method, we'd always take the third term from the right.  Even possibly, constraints, like the Buying Method is always 2 or 3 chacters in length.  The more "rules" you can give us, the better chance of finding a formula.  Give us lots of examples, with the result!

Comment: But your third example makes it unlikely we'll get an answer.  How to extract "Snail" when the term PlainSnail is between underscores, and capital letters seem irrelevant.  I feel your data is just too non-standard to be able to make this work - unless you can find the logic and words to say how you know that Snail is the Campaign Name in that example...?

Comment: I just thought of something else.  If you have a list of all of the existing campaign names, then yes, we could search these strings to see which campaign they match.  Would that help you?  You can then process the row that this string came from, and know which campaign it is associated with.  If this is what you want, please share a sample sheet.  See here for how to share:  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/138382/how-to-share-a-google-sheets-demo-spreadsheet/138383#138383

Answer (score 0):

If there's a limited number of campaigns you can make a list of all known campaign names and then extract them from longer string.

How to make a list.
If you put in B2:

```
=regexextract(a2,"Q1BeesAreGettingThem|slimyinfluencer|Snail|potatogoestohollywood") - this will extract the name of campaign found.
```

If there's for example 50 campaign names and growing, you can make a column with your campaign names (let's say in column D)

Then you join all these names into one expression and put into regexectract:

```
=regexextract(a2,join("|",D2:D))
```